VS code not enforcing environment variables
So I have this webapp running flask, react, and sqlalchemy for the db. I'm now prepping for hosting so I'm testing with setting different environment varibales (development, testing, production). However when I set the environment varibles in VS code's command shell
set FLASK_ENV=development
set FLASK_APP=run.py

I'm getting this error:
FLASK_ENV is set to: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\Python\Hacklab-sem-1\remoire\run.py", line 5, in <module>
    app = create_app()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\Python\Hacklab-sem-1\remoire\app\__init__.py", line 26, in create_app
    db.init_app(app)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 355, in init_app
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set.

I have this line in the run.py file
print(f"FLASK_ENV: {os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV')}")

and as you can see it says that the env is set to None, however if I set the env manually in the run.py file itself before calling create_app() using
os.environ['FLASK_ENV'] = 'development'

everything runs. From what I can tell the scope seems to be correct, before running the commands I change the directory to be directly in the remoire folder which is where the run.py is as well as the app folder, I just can't seem to figure out the issue. Here is the create_app() function where the problem arrises
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    env = os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV', 'production')

    if env == 'development':
        app.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')
    elif env == 'testing':
        app.config.from_object('config.TestingConfig')
    else:
        app.config.from_object('config.ProductionConfig')

   
    db.init_app(app)
    .
    .
    .


If you set the variables in a shell, they apply for exactly that shell, no other shell or VSC run.

@KlausD. yes I know that, even in the same shell it doesnt work.

VS code debuggers start a new shell each time, so even if you write all the commands in the same shell, as soon as it runs with debug set to true all env variables are reset.

Follow these steps if you want to use os.environ.get:

Go to Manage > Settings
Under terminal.integrated.env, choose your OS and edit in JSON

{
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}


Try resetting the app cache.
If you are in windows you have to create a environment variable by creating going to windows registers

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
